# Writing my own 2-node or 3-node Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am supposed to create a Binary Search Tree or B-Tree with a maximum of three nodes. Any one "parent" or "child" node can hold 1 or 2 values making it so that it can either have 2 or 3 "child" pointers on it.

For example: This is okay because there is only a maximum of 2 values in each set

`23 30 
 / | \
12 25 [35 38]`

Where as this is not: because the root has 3 values in it and 4 "child" nodes

`12 15 18
/  | |  \
4 14 16 20`

I was able to write my own Binary Search Tree, but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to turn that into a 2node or 3node Binary Search tree.

Could someone help me implement a 2node or 3node binary search tree code with the regular binary tree.

```
public class TreeNode<K extends Comparable<K>, V> 
{
    public K key;
    public V value;

    public TreeNode<K,V> left;
    public TreeNode<K,V> right;


    public TreeNode(K key, V value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

}
```

The tough part comes to when I need to change the actual `BST` Class. I know the  put is going to change quite a bit because we have to check and see if it is a 2 node or a 3 node.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  public class BST<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
{
    private TreeNode<K, V> root;

    public BST()
    {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public void put(K key, V value)
    {
        if (root == null)
            root = new TreeNode<>(key, value);
        else
            put(root, key, value);
    }

    private void put(TreeNode<K, V> current, K key, V value)
    {
        int n = key.compareTo(current.key);

        if (n == 0)
        {
            current.value = value;
            return;
        }
        else if (n < 0)
        {
            if (current.left == null)
            {
                current.left = new TreeNode<>(key, value);
                return;
            }
            else
                put(current.left, key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (current.right == null)
            {
                current.right = new TreeNode<>(key, value);
                return;
            }
            else
                put(current.right, key, value);
        }
    }

    public V get(K key)
    {
        return get(root, key);
    }

    private V get(TreeNode<K,V> current, K key)
    {
        if (current == null)
            return null;
        else 
        {
            int n = key.compareTo(current.key);

            if (n==0)
                return current.value;
            else if (n < 0)
                return get(current.left, key);
            else
                return get(current.right, key);
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size(root);
    }

    private int size(TreeNode<K,V> current)
    {
        if(current == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return size(current.left) + size(current.right) + 1;
    }

    public int depth()
    {
        return depth(root) - 1;
    }

    private int depth(TreeNode<K,V> current)
    {
        if(current == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return Math.max(depth(current.left), depth(current.right)) + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you struggling? What are you missing? By the way, a 2-3 tree is not a *binary* tree.

Comment: My apologies, maybe a Balanced Binary search tree would have been better. I am having trouble on just how to go about doing this. I am not that good with recursion, and I understand the concept of how the self balancing tree works and the steps necessary, but I just cannot figure out how to implement them. @Zulan

Comment: @JohnDoe It's important to edit your title to be as accurate as possible, so that knowledgeable people can find it.